# Extendible Hashing, doubling the size of an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hashtable

I'm trying to implement Extendible Hashing in C++

There's a struct which acts as an Index and it contains an array of type 'Bucket'

`Bucket * bucket_pointers;`

There's another struct, Bucket, which has an array, which holds my values

`E values[N] = {};`

I've got a more or less working program, with one problem: Everytime I to double the size of my hash table, I'm copying all of my buckets into a new array (twice the size)

```
Index_0
Bucket <n= 3, local_depth=2, 0x100200000>
[12,4,,8,]
Index_1
Bucket <n= 0, local_depth=1, 0x100200028>
[,,,,]
Index_2
Bucket <n= 3, local_depth=2, 0x100200050>
[2,10,6,,]
Index_3
Bucket <n= 0, local_depth=1, 0x100200078>
[,,,,]
```

However, the Bucket with address 0x100200078 should actually point to the bucket with address 0x100200028, i.e. both indices (1 and 3) should point to the same bucket.

Here I'm deciding whether to split a bucket or double the size of my index...

```
while (!bucket_pointers[h%index_size].append(e)){ 
    if(bucket_pointers[h%index_size].local_depth<global_depth){
        split(hashValue);
    }
    else if(bucket_pointers[h%index_size].local_depth==global_depth){
        resize();
    }
}
```

I'm currently doubling the size of my array like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < index_size;  ++i){
            for (size_t j = 0; j < bucket_pointers[i].n;  ++j){ 
                newBucket_pointers[i] = bucket_pointers[i];
                newBucket_pointers[i+index_size] = bucket_pointers[i];
            }
    }
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code. Have you considered using a std::vector<> for the extendable hash table? It'll do all the work for you.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for commenting, I've edited my answer to add some more code. Well, this would be easier of course! However, I'm trying to learn C++, so this is not an option in this case.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading the code correctly, or maybe you're simply doing this a little differently, but a related problem it at least *appears* you're having (and may not know it yet) is the how you're reseating your nodes in the new table. The final hash index for a node is (usually) based on a modulo of the *table size*. If you're doubling the size of the table, you need to *rehash* each node to calculate the (hopefully 50%-probable likelihood) a given node has a new home in the expanded table. bulk copying the array isn't going to do it (again, apologies if I spaced on your code).

Comment: I agree with that. I am also concerned about the fixed number of places in a bucket. Are you planning on adding an index every time a bucket fills up?

Comment: Well, there are two things happening: I'm either resizing my hash table (doubling it) or I'm splitting a bucket (which is also where I'm rehashing each node. 
Exactly, that's how I'm understanding 'Extendible Hashing'. There's a fixed Bucket size, and every time a bucket fills up I'm either: Splitting the Bucket, or Doubling my Hashtable and then splitting the bucket (depending on the global and local depth)

Comment: @intagli clearly So long as you're away of that requirement.

Comment: I've added some more code to show how I'm deciding whether to split a Bucket or double the size of my index

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Bucket * bucket_pointers;` is not an array of Bucket pointers as it's name would imply. It's a pointer to a Bucket (the first Bucket in an array of Buckets to be specific).

So, when you copy the array of buckets to another, you end up with identical copies of buckets each with their own `values` arrays.

```
newBucket_pointers[i] = bucket_pointers[i];
newBucket_pointers[i+index_size] = bucket_pointers[i];
```

If you want `newBucket_pointers[i]` and `newBucket_pointers[i+index_size]` to be pointers that point to the same `Bucket` then the type of `bucket_pointers` (and `newBucket_pointers`) should actually be `Bucket**`. Then `bucket_pointers` is a pointer to a `Bucket*` and `bucket_pointers[i]` is a pointer to a Bucket. That way `bucket_pointers[i]`, `newBucket_pointers[i]` and `newBucket_pointers[i+index_size]` would point to the same Bucket. I recommend a `std::vector<Bucket*> bucket_pointers` instead though for easier memory management.

If instead, you intend to copy the Buckets as you do now but have their `values` member point to a shared array, then you can keep `bucket_pointers` as it is and you need to change the type of `values` to a pointer and allocate the array separately. If you want to share the array this way, you should probably use a `shared_ptr` to make the eventual deallocation easier.

Comment: This sounds right! However, I'm still not quite sure how I'd go about implementing this. Would I have to add a pointer in the Bucket object, which would either point to the values array in the same Bucket object or to another values array in another bucket object?
And it'd be a pointer to an array of values, like this??
`E (*pointer)[N]; // A pointer to an array of values of type E`

Comment: @intagli: Actually, now that I've read your question again, I'm not sure I've understood correctly. I was assuming that you wanted to copy buckets and have them share same `values` array, but now I think that you want to copy pointers to buckets. Could you verify which you intend to do?

Comment: Well, my intent was to double my hash table, which should consist of buckets or, pointers to those buckets... I.e, hash table index 1 references/contains a bucket and hash table index 3 should point to the same bucket. So if I'm adding a value it should go into the same bucket... Until I'm splitting a Bucket, then I'm distributing the pointers to the old bucket and to the new bucket and rehash the values accordingly. That's the plan at least.

Comment: @intagli: Frankly, I'm not familiar with extendible hashing, but I edited my answer to explain how you can have the indices of `bucket_pointers` to point to a same Bucket. Essentially, you need an array of pointers instead of array of Buckets.

Answer (score 1):

I've included some code below that performs as a very simple hash table.  It is for instructional purpose only and not robust enough for use in a real application.  In real life use the built-in std::unordered_set which works much better.

I avoid the need to change the bucket size, by using a linked list as a bucket that can expand as needed.

Is this example helpful to set you on the right track?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>


class CTable
{
public:
    void Add(const std::string &sKey, int nVal);
    int  Find(const std::string &sKey);

protected:
    size_t Index(const std::string &sKey);

private:
    struct SData
    {
        SData(const std::string &s, int n)
        : sKey(s)
        , nVal(n)
        {
        }
        std::string sKey;
        int         nVal;
    };
    typedef std::list<SData> Bucket_t;
    enum { nBuckets = 24 };
    typedef std::array<Bucket_t, nBuckets> Table_t;
    Table_t m_table;

    const SData *Lookup(const Bucket_t &b, const std::string &sKey);
};

void CTable::Add(const std::string &sKey, int nVal)
{
    size_t nIndex = Index(sKey);
    const SData *p = Lookup(m_table.at(nIndex), sKey);
    if (p)
        throw std::runtime_error("duplicate key");
    m_table.at(nIndex).push_back(SData(sKey, nVal));
}

int CTable::Find(const std::string &sKey)
{
    size_t nIndex = Index(sKey);
    const SData *p = Lookup(m_table.at(nIndex), sKey);
    if (p)
        return p->nVal;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("not found");
}

size_t CTable::Index(const std::string &sKey)
{
    return std::hash<std::string>()(sKey) % m_table.size();
}

const CTable::SData *CTable::Lookup(const CTable::Bucket_t &b, 
                                    const std::string &sKey)
{
    for (const SData &s : b)
        if (s.sKey == sKey)
            return &s;
    return nullptr;
}


int main() 
{
    CTable t;

    t.Add("one", 1);
    t.Add("two", 2);
    t.Add("three", 3);

    assert(2 == t.Find("two"));

    try
    {
        t.Find("four");
        assert(false);
    }
    catch (std::exception &)
    {
    }
    try
    {
        t.Add("two", 3);
        assert(false);
    }
    catch (std::exception &)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @user2079303 already pointed out, what you want is an array of Bucket**.

Let me clarify this with some imagery:

[Extendible-hashing explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDUZP.png)

One thing to remember in case `Bucket** index = new Bucket*[<size_here>]` confuses you,
say you want to make a simple `int`-array.
You would do:

```
int* nums = new int[5];
```

Simply imagine to decrease the number of *-symbols on the right-side since
that is defining what the content-type shall be. And so all you want to store is addresses to Buckets. Thus the `index` containing 1 or more **pointer** to Buckets.

Hope it helps!